# Не открывается модальное окно bootstrap(необычный баг)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Не открывается модальное окно у конкретного пользователя. не открывается, ни по клику ни по $('#modalnew').modal() из консоли. Пробовали с разных браузеров заходили под разными аккаунтами. скачивали пустые браузеры последних версий. не работает. причем не отрабатывает именно JS (не добавляется атрибут show).

У остальных пользователей(на других компах) все работает нормально. В чем тут может быть проблема ?

Comment: Единственный браузер в котором у пользователя работает - это Tor